# Python: Preventing elements being appended to the same list over and over

Tags: python, list, class, oop, append

I was working on my first OOP project, it is a random number generator, that generates a number of random numbers in a given range:

```
import random
import math

resList=[]

class randomInRange:
    def getRandom(self, start, end, quantity):
        for i in range(quantity):
            selList = range(start, end)
            resNum = random.choice(selList)
            resList.append(resNum)

        return (resList)

RR=randomInRange()
```

Then, I would type this in the Python Shell:

```
    (RR.getRandom(0,10,10))
```

and it would give something like this: [2, 2, 1, 4, 8, 1, 0, 7, 4, 5]
But if I call the function again, it would append the new generatated
numbers to the same list. So it would like something like this: [2, 2, 1, 4, 8, 1, 0, 7, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 1, 8, 6, 7, 5, 4, 4]

How do I get around this? How can I prevent fresh data to be appended to same list over and over again, which makes the list useless?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make it a set - the values have to be unique.  Or check to see if a value appears before you insert it.

Comment: I kinda need to learn about sets :/ I have just started python :) thanks for help :)

Comment: @duffymo That's not the problem :p

Comment: @user2754106 There's a good tutorial about them on the [official python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) :)

Comment: @ Haidro thanks for the heads-up! :) gonna check them out ASAP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `resList` is a global variable and you never wipe its contents when calling `randomInRange`. You should just create the list in the function:

```
class randomInRange:
    def getRandom(self, start, end, quantity):
        resList = []
        for i in range(quantity):
            selList = range(start, end)
            resNum = random.choice(selList)
            resList.append(resNum)
        return (resList)
```

Note that your function can be replaced with a list comprehension too:

```
def getRandom(self, start, end, quantity):
    temp = range(start, end)
    return [random.choice(temp) for _ in range(quantity)]
```

Comment: Oh god, I don't know how I couldn't think of this, Jesus :S Thanks, sir! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import math

resList=[]

class randomInRange:
    def getRandom(self, start, end, quantity):
        for i in range(quantity):
            selList = range(start, end)
            resNum = random.choice(selList)
        if resNum not in resList:
                resList.append(resNum) 

        return (resList)

RR=randomInRange()
print RR.getRandom(0,10,10)
```

Comment: This isn't right. `print RR.getRandom(0,10,10)` again. And again... and again ;). And you'll see :)

Comment: Teah that is why I asked people :D And got a good answer, thanks for contrabution!

Answer (score 0):

Or even simplier would be the following

```
import random

def getRandom(start, end, quantity):
    return [random.choice(range(start, end)) for _ in range(quantity)]

print getRandom(0, 10, 10)
```

Comment: Hmm. This is indeed compact and simple, thanks for the answer :)